# How can I resolve a 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url returned on locustio script?

Tags: python-3.x, load-testing, locust

I am trying to write a load test script with locustio, the task is to first log in and pick access_token from the login response, then the access_token is parsed as a request header for the second API request.

Below is my script:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task, between
import json



class UserBehavior(TaskSet):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(UserBehavior, self).__init__(parent)

        self.token = ""
        self.headers = {}

    def on_start(self):
        """this starts before anything else"""
        self.token = self.login()
        self.headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.token}




    def login(self):

        resp = self.client.post("/tologin",json={"username": "user_name","password": "password"})

        return json.loads(resp._content)['data']['access_token']







    @task()
    def book_trip(self):

        self.client.post("/go/trips/request",json={
   "origin": {
    "address": "pick_up_address",
    "lat": 6.4,
    "lng": 3.5
  },
   "destination":{
       "address": "Sailor's Bar",
        "lat": 6.4,
        "lng": 3.4
   },
   "auto_dispatch": "true",
   "is_cash": "false",
   "user_id":"uuid",
   "service_id": "svdid"
},headers=self.headers)


class CustomerAppUser(HttpLocust):
    host = "my_base_url"
    task_set = UserBehavior
    wait_time = between(5,15)
```

Please what am I doing wrong? why is it returning

> 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm... It is really hard to see what is wrong. I would suggest NOT initializing self.headers and self.token (because you'll get a more obvious better error if login was not executed for some reason). Also you can move the contents of login() into on_start(). Your current setup would call login() both as a task as well as from on_start, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: But more to the point: try printing self.headers or the access token before making the call, so you are sure about what you are sending.

Comment: @Cyberwiz I did print the access_token and I am getting the access_token. However, I asked the engineer to keep a log for me so I can know how the API is parsing the header on the postman, the only difference I could see was that the token value was on the next line after "Bearer" while mine was on the same line. I want to replicate that and see what it looks like. I will update you